# Equivalent of browser debugger's Box Model Inspector in kivy

Tags: python, debugging, kivy

What is the equivalent to the browser's "Box Model" Layout Inspector in the browser debugger, but for kivy?

I come from a background of web development, where "UI" debugging is done in a browser. Probably because of widespread rendering issues (w3c standards ambiguity or implementation errors in web browsers), the tools for debugging "why did my HTML render like that!?!" are quite sophisticated in web browsers.

I can simply press `F12` in Firefox (also now Chromium) to open a debugging window, click on the top-left-most button (the element picker), then as I drag my mouse across the page, every distinct element (as well as a tree of breadcrumbs to the given child element) is highlighted.

[image]

If I click on a given UI element, then the html element cooresponding to the UI element is highlighted, all CSS elements are also shown, as well as a "Box Model" in the `Layout` tab that shows me clearly the width, height, margin, padding, and border of the element. This "Box Model" is so extremely helpful to figure out, tweak, and fix UI rendering issues when designing web pages.

[image: Screenshot of the firefox Dev Tool's Box Model]

Enter UI development with kivy, it takes me days instead of minutes to figure out what's going on because I don't know of a similar tool.

I want a way to be able to wrap a given kivy app with some debugger such that, as I hover over widgets in my kivy app, the full tree (breadcrums) of that tree is shown in real-time as I move my mouse across the screen. And if I click somewhere in the app, it dumps for me all of the properties of that widget, such as width, height, spacing, padding, etc (actually just enumerating the entire `__dict__` of the given widget object). And, ideally, a visual representation of that widget and its sizing is displayed, like the "Box Model" screenshot above.

What's the best equivalent in kivy development for the web browser's debugger and "Box Model"?

Comment: Not aware of any such built-in tool in `kivy`. But perhaps you can emulate that partially (if not fully) in `kivy` by overriding the behavior of the base ui component i.e.`Widget`.

Answer (score 0):

The Kivy Inspector does some of these things ([Inspector — Kivy 2.2.1 documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.modules.inspector.html)). Note especially that when you open the inspector tab [there is a widget tree hidden behind that bar on the bottom left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3r1BL.png) which took me a couple of months to find.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35267396)